# How multiple users in a Web Application can access the single Google Drive using Google API

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a web application which will create users. And I have a single Google Drive. Once a user is create a folder will be assigned to that user in that Google Drive. That user can access only the folder allocated. Every time the user logs in from the web application the files within the allocated folder are able to view and the user can also upload and download files to that folder only. How this is achieved using Google API.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you are going to need a create a service account for your application.  The application will own the google drive account.

```
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount
```

Then your application is going to have to create the directory for the new user and associate the user with the directory's fileid (remember directorys are just files in google drive)  the directory name could change so save the file id not the directory name to be sure.

Then it should simple be a matter of your appilcation uploading / viewing the files to the correct directory depending upon who is loged in.  Since you will have the id for the directory it will be easy enough to list them the files already in that directory.  as well as uploading directly to that directory.